# Why isn't this command returning to shell after &?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-14.04

In Ubuntu 14.04, I created the following bash script:

```
flock -nx "$1" xdg-open "$1" &
```

The idea is to lock the file specified in $1 (flock), then open it in my usual editor (xdg-open), and finally return to prompt, so I can open other files in sequence (&).

However, the & isn't working as expected. I need to press Enter to make the shell prompt appear again. In simpler constructs, such as

```
gedit test.txt &
```

it works as it should, returning the prompt immediately. I think it has to do with the existence of two commands in the first line. What am I doing wrong, please?

EDIT

The prompt is actually there, but it is somehow "hidden". If I issue the command

```
sudo ./edit error.php
```

it replies with

```
Warning: unknown mime-type for "error.php" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no "view" mailcap rules found for type "application/octet-stream"
Opening "error.php" with Geany  (application/x-php)
__
```

The errors above are not related to the question. But instead of __ I see nothing. I know the prompt is there because I can issue other commands, like `ls`, and they work. But the question remains: WHY the prompt is hidden? And how can I make it show normally?

Comment: It works for me. The output is a little confusing because I get an error message: `"** (gedit:29358): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-PmNGYCW3ks: Connection refused"`. Do you get an error message? Perhaps your prompt was printed, but it was followed by other output. What happens if you just type another command, ignoring the apparent lack of a prompt?

Comment: It probably *is* returning to the shell, but the prompt is subsequently overwritten by output. Try just blindly typing `ls` and hitting enter, and you'll probably see that the shell is still there accepting commands, and that this is a purely cosmetic issue.

Comment: Yes, you both are correct. The shell was hidden by other output. Anyway, WHY is this happening? And how to make it look normal (so that other people using this in the future won't come back here thinking the prompt is not there)?

Comment: Update your question to mention this point *and* show the exact output you're seeing.

Comment: The shell prompt came back before the command completed printing its output. There are 2 things I can think of. The first one is obvious, you can simply ignore and toss away the printed output of your command by redirecting the output to `/dev/null`. Side effect is you could miss some important message. The second is to simply sleep a little then echo or clear the screen so the user will see the prompt after `echo` or `clear` is executed.

Comment: Answers should be accepted by clicking the checkbox next to them, **not** by editing them into the question.

Comment: (Also, `EDIT` delimiters are frowned on somewhat here -- the edit history of a question or answer is there for everyone to see, so the goal of edits should be to make a resulting question that reads and flows cleanly, rather than to maintain a clear timeline).

Comment: ...if you're using something as a solution that wasn't given as an answer (perhaps it was a comment), go ahead and add it as an answer yourself!

Comment: @alvits: Your idea of using `sleep` is the one the OP used. Do you want to post an answer? (If not, I can steal your idea and add it to my answer, but I want to give you the first shot at it.)

Comment: @KeithThompson - go for it. I like the way you present answers.

Answer (score 4):

> **Why isn't this command returning to shell after &?**

It is.

You're running a command in the background. The shell prints a new prompt as soon as the command is launched, without waiting for it to finish.

According to your latest comment, the background command is printing some message to your screen. A simple example of the same thing:

```
$ echo hello &
$ hello
```

The cursor is left at the beginning of the line after the `$ hello`.

As far as the shell is concerned, it's printed a prompt and is waiting a new command. It doesn't know or care that a background process has messed up your display.

One solution is to redirect the command's output to somewhere other than your screen, either to a file or to `/dev/null`. If it's an error message, you'll probably have to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr.

```
flock -nx "$1" xdg-open "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

(This assumes you don't care about the content of the message.)

Another option, pointed out in a comment by alvits, is to sleep for a second or so after executing the command, so the message appears *followed* by the next shell prompt.  The `sleep` command is executed in the foreground, delaying the printing of the next prompt. A simple example:

```
$ echo hello & sleep 1
hello
[1] + Done                       echo hello
$
```

or for your example:

```
flock -nx "$1" xdg-open "$1" & sleep 1
```

This assumes that the error message is printed in the first second. That's probably a valid assumption for you example, but it might not be in general.

Comment: What if I do care?

Comment: @Rodrigo: Already addressed: "... either to a file or to `/dev/null`"

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do it using sleep, see my second edit. It has the advantage of showing any messages (important or not) right on screen.

Comment: 1st line: flock -nx "$1" xdg-open "$1" & 2nd line: sleep 1. This worked for me. Add it to your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the command is doing what you think it does.
Have you tried to run it twice to see if the lock cannot be obtained the second time.
Well, if you do it, you will see that it doesn't fail because `xdg-open` is forking to exec the editor. Also if it fails you expect some indication.

You should use something like this

```
flock -nx "$1" -c "gedit '$1' &" || { echo "ERROR"; exit 1; }
```

Comment: This is a perfectly fine way to use `flock`, but I don't agree with its premise that the use pattern the OP is leveraging is not also acceptable. From `man flock`, among the supported use patterns: `flock [options] file|directory command [arguments]`

Comment: BTW, why the `-e` argument to `echo`? It's needlessly making your code incompatible with POSIX (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, particularly including the APPLICATION USAGE section), while not adding any value.

Comment: ...I mean, the `flock command [arguments]` approach also involves creating an FD, so it also survives a fork just as the approach where you're doing that work explicitly does; it's just a question of whether it's the flock command or the shell doing the `open()`.

Comment: Correct. `-e` removed. I'm not saying the other way of using `flock` is incorrect but it does not serve the original purpose of locking the file while editing.

Comment: ...nope, I wasn't mistaken. Run `flock -x foo bash -c 'ls -l /proc/self/fd'` -- you'll see the child process inherits a file descriptor on the lock. Thus, that lock can still be held even after the child self-daemonizes.

Comment: (The case where this wouldn't work is if your editor closes file descriptors it doesn't recognize during daemonization -- but that would also break the locking with the hardcoded FD 9 approach given in this example too).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, you are 100% right, I updated my answer to a simplest form

Comment: It worked the way I showed in my last edit, but it wasn't "locking" the file. It just warned that somebody else changed the file. I've been told that flock doesn't work well with NFS. Seems that I'll have to use fcntl, which is compatible with NFS and with OS X (also used here).